# How to get total number of nodes in an XML in MarkLogic Database

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have an XML like below in my database:

```
<PersonalData>
  <Person>
    <Name></Name>
    <Age></Age>
    <AccountNo>
      <Number>123<Number>
      <SwiftCode>1235<SwiftCode>
    </AccountNo>
    <AccountNo>
      <Number>15523<Number>
      <SwiftCode>188235<SwiftCode>
    </AccountNo>
  </Person>
</PersonalData>
```

in this XML, I have multiple `AccountNo` nodes and I have around 1M similar records in my database. I want to identify the count of `AccountNo` nodes in my entire database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way in which you can report the count of `AccountNo` elements would be to   use an XPath and count:

```
count(//AccountNo)
```

You can also use `cts:search` and specify the `AccountNo` in the `$expression` XPath, and then `count()` the results:

```
count(cts:search(//AccountNo, cts:true-query()))
```

Another way to get a count of all the distinct `AccountNo` elements would be to run a [CoRB](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2) job to select the docs that have those elements, and then in the process module return a line for every element in the doc and write the results to a text file. Below is an example [**OPTIONS-FILE**](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#OPTIONS-FILE) that could be used to achieve that:

```
URIS-MODULE=INLINE-XQUERY|let $uris := cts:uris('',(),cts:element-query(xs:QName("AccountNo"), cts:true-query())) return (count($uris), $uris)
PROCESS-MODULE=INLINE-XQUERY|declare variable $URI external; doc($URI)//AccountNo ! 1
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask
EXPORT-FILE-NAME=AccountNoCounts.txt
DISK-QUEUE=true
```

Then you could get the line count from the result file, which would tell you have many elements there are: `wc -l AccountNoCounts.txt`

If you need to be able to get this count often, and need the response to be fast, you could create a [TDE](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE) that projects rows for each of the `AccountNo` elements and then could and could select the count with SQL (e.g. `SELECT count(1) FROM Person.AccountNo`) or use the [Optic API](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/OpticAPI) against that TDE and [`op.count()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/op.count).